# Junit testing in play with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError has been caught, Java heap space

Tags: java, testing, junit, playframework

I'm trying to do some junit testing for a web app and I keep getting the OutOfMemoryError. I know where its happening in the code but I'm not sure why its doing it.

```
Survey survey = new Survey();
        SurveyLayoutColumn column1 = new SurveyLayoutColumn();
        column1.addAnswerSpace(new Answer());
        SurveyLayoutColumn column2 = new SurveyLayoutColumn();
        column2.addAnswerSpace(new Answer());
        column2.addAnswerSpace(new Answer());
        SurveyLayoutColumn column3 = new SurveyLayoutColumn();
        column3.addAnswerSpace(new Answer());
        survey.addLayoutColumn(column1);
        survey.addLayoutColumn(column2);
        survey.addLayoutColumn(column3);
        survey.addQuestion(new Question());
        survey.addQuestion(new Question());
        survey.addQuestion(new Question());
        survey.addQuestion(new Question());
        Application app = new controllers.Application();
        app.saveSurvey(survey);
        long count = Survey.count();
        assertEquals(count,0);
```

It happens at app.saveSurvey(surey) and here is the code for that method

```
public static void saveSurvey(Survey survey) {
        System.out.println("Survey title is: " + survey.title);

        survey.published = true;
        survey.save();

        Map<String, Object> viewData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        viewData.put("status", "success");

        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();

        serializer
            .include("status")
            .exclude("*");

        renderJSON(serializer.serialize(viewData));
    }
```

any help would be great on why this is happening.

EDIT:
Here is the trace

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:106)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what does this code snippet `long count = Survey.count();` do?

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. thats all it says

Comment: returns number of surveys in database.

Comment: post the full stack trace. Not just the name of the Exception.

Comment: thats what it says for the trace

Comment: So you don't know what line is the last one executed?? Add log statements to find out. It's probably the serializer. You probably have a cycle.

Comment: got this trace after:

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that Unbinder.unbind() is in a loop, calling itself, and on each call it absorbs a bit of memory; it could do that with the stack, which it is using on every call, or with something connected to AbstractStringBuilder.

Out of Memory is one time when the stack trace doesn't necessarily point to the problem line; the stack trace usually shows some cycle like this in these cases.